# Why does my "Where SDDOCO = 128" return results when the the unrestricted query does not

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

so I have this problem with oracle, I have this massive query which is returning results but we noticed a specific subset of results are not being returned.

When We check for a specific record we know is missing form the "Wide Open" query it is not found.. but if we add the "And SDDOCO = 127454" to this same query and nothing else is added or removed we suddenly get the result.  See the code below.

Original query which is not returning the result we want:

```
Select * FROM PRODDTA.F42119 
left join proddta.F554202x on trim(SDURRF) = trim(TMUSRRSV1) and SDDOCO = TMDOCO
LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F4101 ON IMITM = SDITM
LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F41002 ON UMITM = SDITM AND SDMCU = UMMCU AND SDUOM = UMUM AND UMRUM = imuom1
left join PRODDTA.F41003 on UCUM = SDWTUM and UCRUM = ''LB''
Left JOin (SELECT UMMCU as MCU, UMITM as ITM, UMUM as UM, max(CASE WHEN UMRUM = ''LB'' THEN UMCONV/10000000 ELSE UMCONV/10000000 * UCCONV/10000000 END) AS CONV 
            FROM PRODDTA.F41002
            LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F41003
              ON UMRUM = UCUM
            WHERE (UCRUM = ''LB'' OR UMRUM = ''LB'')
            GROUP BY UMMCU, UMITM, UMUM) CONV2
  ON MCU = SDMCU AND ITM = SDITM AND UM = SDUOM
WHERE SDADDJ >= FISCALPERIODSTART(13,1) 
and SDADDJ <= FISCALPERIODEND(13,12) 
and  SDLNTY = ''S'' 
AND SDSOQS > 0 
and not ((SDLTTR = 980 AND SDNXTR = 999) OR SDSOCN = SDUORG) 
and SDSRP1 <> ''BLK'' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN NVL(TRIM(TMURRF),'' '') = '' '' then SDURRF ELSE TMURRF END
```

Here is the code that will then Return a single result for the specific order we are looking for.

```
Select * FROM PRODDTA.F42119 
left join proddta.F554202x on trim(SDURRF) = trim(TMUSRRSV1) and SDDOCO = TMDOCO
LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F4101 ON IMITM = SDITM
LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F41002 ON UMITM = SDITM AND SDMCU = UMMCU AND SDUOM = UMUM AND UMRUM = imuom1
left join PRODDTA.F41003 on UCUM = SDWTUM and UCRUM = ''LB''
Left JOin (SELECT UMMCU as MCU, UMITM as ITM, UMUM as UM, max(CASE WHEN UMRUM = ''LB'' THEN UMCONV/10000000 ELSE UMCONV/10000000 * UCCONV/10000000 END) AS CONV 
            FROM PRODDTA.F41002
            LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F41003
              ON UMRUM = UCUM
            WHERE (UCRUM = ''LB'' OR UMRUM = ''LB'')
            GROUP BY UMMCU, UMITM, UMUM) CONV2
  ON MCU = SDMCU AND ITM = SDITM AND UM = SDUOM
WHERE SDADDJ >= FISCALPERIODSTART(13,1) 
and SDADDJ <= FISCALPERIODEND(13,12) 
and  SDLNTY = ''S'' 
AND SDSOQS > 0 
and not ((SDLTTR = 980 AND SDNXTR = 999) OR SDSOCN = SDUORG) 
and SDSRP1 <> ''BLK''
And SDDOCO = '123456' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN NVL(TRIM(TMURRF),'' '') = '' '' then SDURRF ELSE TMURRF END
```

Now my understanding is that if the second query returns a Row for SDDOCO 123456 then the first query which returns a number of results should also include this row in that group of results but it does not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd blame `GROUP BY`. Try removing it and check output.

Comment: OMG, that is it.. Thanks sometimes it just needs a different set of eyes!

Comment: NP. it's strange that you don't get "not a group by expression" error. Also, side note -Oracle treats empty string as NULL, so your NVL does nothing.